# Trouble installing Visual Studio 2010 on Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently using genuine Windows Vista Home Premium, and tried installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, however the installation setup reports a hindrance asking me to install Windows Vista Service Pack 1.

When I check the properties of my Computer, Windows Edition section lists the information as show in the image link below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T82E.jpg]

My predicament is, should i manually download the said Service pack 1 and install it, or should I upgrade to Windows Vista Ultimate?
Which of the 2 options would serve to fix my problem?
Or is the solution something different

Ps. here's the image to the problem impeding my Visual Studio 2010 intsallation:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZDBh.jpg]

Comment: You should install Windows Vista Service Pack 1.

Comment: update first to Sp1, next to Sp2 and install all updates offered from Windows Update. Now install the Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You need to install the services packs in order to install Visual Studio 2010.  What does upgrading to Windows Vista Ultimate have to do with anything?

Comment: When I check for updates via the 'Windows Update' feature available, I get a variety of updates, but none that reads Service Pack. Here's a link i.stack.imgur.com/OEAM6.jpg. Microsoft's website deprecates manually downloading and installing the Service Pack as it is around 450 Mb in size, whereas if I were to update it via 'Windows Update', it would be 65 Mb, not seeing the feature in the list of available updates, I felt updating to Windows Ultimate might resolve it, now I know it won't.

Comment: So could anybody help me install it via 'Windows Update', instead of having to do it manually? I don't know which issue is preventing me from installing it the convenient way!

Comment: install the Sp1 and Sp2 via Exe from the downloadcenter: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/Results.aspx?q=Vista%20Sp1&form=DLC http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/Results.aspx?q=Vista%20Sp2&form=DLC

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to resort to manual installation this way though! =)

Comment: is the issue now fixed after installing the Sp1 and Sp2 + all updates?

Comment: I only installed Sp1 and Sp2, and yes, it has been resolved.
A heartfelt thank you to you Sir for your concern and support! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests

[image]

, you first have to install the [Windows Vista Sp1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/Results.aspx?q=Vista%20Sp1&form=DLC), next the [Windows Vista Sp2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/Results.aspx?q=Vista%20Sp2&form=DLC), now all Updates from Windows Update. Now when your system is up to date, install the Visual Studio 2010.